# zsh: bus error ./array_stack on using pointers to access the stack elements

Tags: c++

the code run fine when I used the dot operator for accessing the elements of the stack. But on using pointers to access the stack structure, I was getting this error. zsh: bus error  ./array_stack. Can anyone help me in resolving this.The code is as follows:

```
 #include<iostream>

 using namespace std;
//implementing the stack using an array

struct Stack{
int size;//size of the array
int top;//points to the last element of the array
int * arr;

};

int IsEmpty(struct Stack *ptr){
if(ptr->top == -1){
    return 1;
}
else{
    return 0;
}

 }

 int main(){
//one way of making the stack
// struct Stack S;
// S.size=43;
// S.top=-1;
// S.arr=(int *)malloc(S.size*sizeof(int));

//second way of making the stack
struct Stack *S;
S->size=54;
S->top=-1;
S->arr=(int *)malloc(S->size*sizeof(int));
if(IsEmpty(S)){
    cout<<"The array is empty.";
} 
return 0; 

}
```

Comment: `struct Stack *S;` S has never been set to point to an object of Stack. It's an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `struct Stack *S;` declares an uninitialized pointer that points to an indeterminate location. There is no memory allocated for the struct data. `struct Stack *S = malloc(sizeof(*S));` would allocate memory for the data and point the pointer at it.

Comment: Your Stack Object doesn't need to be a pointer in the first place.

Comment: Are you programming in `C` or `C++`?  Iostream and namespace indicate C++, but the original tag was `[C]`, and you're using `malloc()` not `new()`, etc.

Comment: @Kingsley C++, someone else edited it to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: This question was originally tagged as `C` (not `C++`).  I'm still not sure which way it will go.  I will modify this answer to use C++ when it's clear.

The problem is you're defining `S` as a *pointer to a Stack*, but you never tell it to point to anything.  So `S` is pointing to *somewhere* in memory (you probably don't own), and the `S->size = 54` is trying to modify the content of that memory by writing `54`.

The fact that the code is generating a "[Bus Error](https://busfoundation.org/answers-on-questions/question-what-is-a-bus-error.html#What_is_bus_error_in_C)" indicates that `S` actually contains a memory address that is outside of valid memory range.

To fix it, `S` should be pointing at a stack:

```
struct Stack myStack;         // myStack is an actual stack
struct Stack *S = &myStack;   // a pointer to myStack
```

Obviously this method creates a `Stack` that is uninitialised. A nice way to do this sort of thing is to make a function that creates a new `Stack`, initialises it, then returns a pointer to it:

```
struct Stack *createStack( int capacity )
{
    assert( capacity > 0 );

    struct Stack *new_stack = malloc( sizeof( struct Stack ) );
    if ( new_stack != NULL )
    {
        new_stack->size = capacity;
        new_stack->top  = -1;
        new_stack->arr  = malloc( capacity * sizeof( int ) );  

        // If we failed to allocate array memory: clean-up & return NULL
        if ( new_stack->arr == NULL )
        {
            free( new_stack );
            new_stack = NULL;
        }
    }

    return new_stack;
}

// Matching function to free a stack allocated by createStack()
void freeStack( struct Stack *s )
{
    assert( s != NULL );
    assert( s->arr != NULL );

    free( s->arr );    // release the array part first
    free( s );         // release the struct itself
}
```

Then in your code, it can be called:

```
struct Stack *s = createStack( 54 );

// ...

freeStack( s );   // clean up when done
```

Comment: I would suggest rather than wrap your code in a conditional if `new_stack != NULL` you can simply immediately return `NULL` if `new_stack == NULL`. Then proceed with the rest of the code one less indentation level deep. Likewise with handling the allocation of `new_stack->arr`.

Comment: @Chris - While there is nothing wrong with your suggestion, my personal preference is to almost-always return from the last line in the function.  I feel this approach makes the code easier to follow.  Yes, if the indentation becomes too deep it needs to be mitigated, but that's rarely a significant problem.

Comment: It is a matter of opinion, as the result remains the same.

Comment: It's beyond the scope of the OP, but it's something beginners should learn early... Those two `malloc()` calls want to be matched with two `free()`s... in the appropriate sequence. Otherwise, nice answer... :-)